# Dynamic label that changes based upon event handler

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet of HTML that is part of a form where there are two input's. Via CSS I have managed to make the label associated with each input to sit inside their corresponding input to act as a placeholder.

Now, with some standard JS (not JQuery I'm afraid), I wanted to capture the event that the user does (i.e. on a mouse click or keyboard press) on the input and dynamically change the look and feel of the label.

http://jsfiddle.net/8nBAQ/2/

The conditions that I need to meet are:

1. When a user clicks on the input for the first time. The label changes colour to a light grey.  After click, if the user then enters a character, the label disappears and the character you have just pressed is displayed instead.
2. When a user clicks on the input for the first time. The label changes colour to a light grey.  After click, if the user then clicks or tabs away from the input, the label changes colour back to it's original state of black.
3. After entering a few characters into the input, if the user decides to delete the whole set of characters by either pressing backspace deleting each character until none are left or highlighting the whole set of characters with a mouse and presses the delete key, the label appears but is in a light grey colour.

Any help you can offer with the JS would be great!

Thanks
-JaXL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I added the following to the input tag and label

```
    <label class="label-inside" for="input1" id="input1_label" title="Enter input 1">Input 1</label>
  <ul class="form-input">
    <li>
      <input type="text" id="input1" name="myInput1" value="" autocomplete="off" title="Enter Input 1" onblur="handleBlur(this, document.getElementById('input1_label'))" 
      onkeydown="handleFirstClick(event, this, document.getElementById('input1_label'))"
      onkeyup="handleKey(this, document.getElementById('input1_label'))" />
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And here is my Javascript

```
<script>


    function handleBlur(input, label )
    {
        if ( !input.value || input.value.length == 0)
        {
            label.style.display = 'block';
            label.style.color = 'black';
            label.clickedBefore = false;
        }
    }

    function handleFirstClick(e, input, label )
    {
        if ( !label.clickedBefore )
        {
            label.clickedBefore = true;
            e.preventDefault();
            label.style.color = 'red';
        }

    }

    function handleKey(input, label)
    { 
      console.log("handling key up : " + input.value.length);
      label.style.display = 'none';

      if (!input.value || input.value.length == 0 )
      {
         label.style.display = 'block';
         label.style.color = 'red';
      }      
     }
</script>
```

Let me know if something else is needed.

EDIT : adding code to add all handlers at once according to input_id.

```
window.onload = function(){

    console.log("windows loaded");
    var labels = {}
    var all_labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for ( var i = 0; i < all_labels.length; i++)
    {
        labels[all_labels[i].getAttribute("for")] = all_labels[i];
    }


    function attachHandlers( input_id )
    {
        var input = document.getElementById(input_id);
        var label = labels[input_id];
        input.onclick = function(e){handleFirstClick(e, input, label)};
        input.onkeyup = function(e){handleKey(input, label)};
        input.onblur = function(e){handleBlur(input, label)};
    }

     var attachInput = ["input1"];
     for ( var j =0; j <attachInput.length; j++)
     {
         attachHandlers(attachInput[j]);
      }

}
```

Comment: I used "red" instead of light-grey.. easier to debug

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have just tried to access your JF but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Can you check [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/qaV49/1/).. I am kind of new to fiddle myself and for some reason it didn't save my previous changes.. probably need to click "update".

Comment: Yes, this one works. After having a look, it seems now that if you click on the input twice, it goes black (i.e. the condition where you are meant to be clicking away from the input) when it should be red. Also, the red text comes up when you enter the first character but it's not showing the character and only appears after the second character has been entered. This condition should clear the input and just show what you are typing.

Comment: oh ok.. i probably didn't understand you correctly. just change the `onkeydown` to `onclick`. and that should resolve the issue. I updated my fiddle. does it work properly now?

Comment: can you repost your JF please?

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for in terms of event handling. Probably asking the impossible here but is there a way we can control the different conditions without id's on the label and having to re-write the events for each input - say something like event handling in a function?

Comment: I added a method on window load. Now you can remove the handlers from tag, and simply add the input_id you want to the array in the function and it should work.

Comment: is it possible to do another JF example please?

Comment: only if you promise to really like my answer :) [a new jf](http://jsfiddle.net/qaV49/5/)

Comment: I like your answer very much! :-) It's precisely what I am looking for and you are being a massive help. One last question, so if I have two input's, how to attach the event handling to it without interfering with the other one?

Comment: ah, another question I'm afraid. I noticed that if I click on the input twice (without any characters entered) as per it should be it's changing from black to red but if I click again it seems to briefly go black again and then to red. Is there some way of putting extra logic to identify that it's already red so there's no need to go black for that brief moment?

Comment: that is great what you managed to do. :-) One little niggly bug that I can't seem to get around is the onblur (when it goes red) function. It seems that if you click on the label it starts off going red (as it should be) but when you click away it stay red rather than black. However, this isn't a bug if click anywhere on the input but not on the label, it works as it should be. Here's my newer version of JF with some enhancements - [my JF](http://jsfiddle.net/8nBAQ/5/)

Comment: also, another bug is if you click on the input but not on the label, it goes red and then if you click on the input again but on the label it briefly goes black before going red again (should stay red and is similar to bug mentioned in my 5th comment)